# Почему запускаются 2 задачи apscheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

```
def test():
    print('hi')

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')
job = scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
```

Вот такой вывод в консоли:

```
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "test" to job store "default"
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "test" to job store "default"
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
```

Comment: Запустил Ваш код. Добавил 2 импорта и `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`, в консоли вижу однократный вывод (3 строки).  Может это у Вас модуль и он 2 раза импортится?

Comment: Попробуйте поместить ваш код вызова шедулера в конструкцию `if __name__ == '__main__':` И вообще возьмите за правило не оставлять "бесхозный" код (не помещённый в классы, функции, либо в эту конструкцию). Меньше глюков потом будете ловить.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо большое! Буду знать! Всё работает!

Comment: Оформил свой комментарий ниже ответом, поставьте ответу галочку, если он вам помог )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие проблемы обычно связаны с многопроцессностью, используемой библиотеками Питона.

Попробуйте поместить ваш код вызова шедулера в такую конструкцию:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')
    job = scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()
```

И вообще возьмите за правило не оставлять у себя никакой "бесхозный" код (не помещённый в классы, функции, либо в эту конструкцию, указанную выше). Весь код, не находящийся внутри чего-то, а размещённый на первом уровне, будет повторно выполнен при запуске шедулером дополнительного процесса, который будет исполнять вашу функцию `test`. Что вы по-видимому и наблюдаете.